# Views Template Suggestions When There are Duplicate Filenames

Tags: views, 6

What does Drupal 6 / Views 2 do when there are two templates with the same filename in different directories?

I just ran into a situation where a row template was accidentally uploaded twice.  Typically, I make `views` subdirectory in my theme, and then a subdirectory per view inside that.  Due to a bad copy/paste, I ended up with

```
site/all/themes/mytheme/views/myview/views-view-unformatted--myview.tpl.php
site/all/themes/mytheme/views/myview2/views-view-unformatted--myview.tpl.php
```

My dev server was picking up the first template.  My live server was picking up the second template, despite being the same set of files as the dev server.  I didn't do the actual live deployment, but as far as I know, the rollout was an exact clone of the files.

I haven't been able to unravel how this actually happened, and would appreciate some insight.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got to the bottom of this.

It looks like when you rebuild the theme registry, [`_theme_build_registry`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/_theme_build_registry/6) invokes [`phptemplate_theme`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes%21engines%21phptemplate%21phptemplate.engine/function/phptemplate_theme/6) via a hook.

`phptemplate_theme` calls [`drupal_find_theme_templates`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/drupal_find_theme_templates/6), which calls [`drupal_system_listing`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_system_listing/6), which calls [`file_scan_directory`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/6).

`file_scan_directory` uses the PHP functions [`opendir`](http://php.net/opendir) and [`readdir`](http://php.net/readdir) to build the list.

No sorting takes place anywhere, so `file_scan_directory` returns in the order which `readdir` returns, which is typically in the order that the files were written to the filesystem.

So, for my problem, the issue boiled down to the dev server and live server writing out the template files in different orders, so the choice as to which to use was different.

Answer (score 0):

You could look and see in your theme registry by dpm-ing in theme_registry_alter() or by turning on devel and visiting /devel/theme/registry and seeing what entry is pointing to what file.

If you don't want to do that on production you could do it locally first and then grab the production database locally.

I would imagine that the registry was rebuilt between the two sites and the first time it picked up one of the files and the second time the other since I don't know of a designed hierarchy for two files in the same level directories in a theme folder.

Don't upvote - this is a speculative answer.

Comment: I rebuilt the theme registry via `drush cc all` a million times on both dev and live when debugging this.  I don't think that was the problem.

Comment: Can you just remove the duplicate file ;)

Comment: Problem is fixed on live server.  This is more of an issue about *why* it happened.